# How do I count the number of occurrences of a value in an array without mutation

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, functional-programming

I currently have an array of arrays that contain parts that all have the same serial number. What I am trying to do is filter out only the parts that have both the same serial number and the same part number. I am currently able to get a list of all the unique part numbers but I can not for the life of me figure out how to pull out only the items that have the same part number and the same serial number. The array is sorted by serial number so

```
dupes = [
[{ sn: 001, partNum: 2505}]
[{ sn: 001, partNum: 9999}]
[{ sn: 001, partNum: 9999}],
[{ sn: 002, partNum: 1234}]
[{ sn: 002, partNum: 1234}],
[{ sn: 003, partNum: 555}]
[{ sn: 003, partNum: 8675}]]
```

What I am trying to get is an array that contains just the duplicates

```
[{ sn: 001, partNum: 9999}]
[{ sn: 001, partNum: 9999}],
[{ sn: 002, partNum: 1234}]
[{ sn: 002, partNum: 1234}]
```

I have been banging my head against this all day and have not found a good solution that does not use mutation. Is there a way to filter out the "SN" if the part number appears twice? I also have to check each part number because in a few cases I have seen the same serial number be used for the two different part numbers two times each, if that makes since. 
Any help would be fantastic... seriously stuck here.

EDIT:

I ended up going about this task a different way. I did however find a good function that allows you to count all the occurrences an item in an array.

```
function count(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((prev, curr) => (prev[curr] = ++prev[curr] || 1, prev), {})
}
```

I found it here https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/567c30

Comment: Can you show an example of your expected output?

Comment: So the result should be [{ sn: 001, partNum: 9999}] and [{ sn: 002, partNum: 1234}] ?

Comment: @JohnEllmore I updated my code to show what ideally I would like to achieve.

Comment: Are you looking for a vanilla JS solution? Or are you open to using libraries like Lodash?

Comment: @JohnEllmore I am trying to keep everything vanilla.

Comment: Why is each object wrapped in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it all the duplicates:

```js
var dupes = [
[{ sn: 001, partNum: 2505}],
[{ sn: 001, partNum: 9999}],
[{ sn: 001, partNum: 9999}],
[{ sn: 002, partNum: 1234}],
[{ sn: 002, partNum: 1234}],
[{ sn: 003, partNum: 555}],
[{ sn: 003, partNum: 8675}]]

var result = [];
for(i =1; i<dupes.length; i++) {
  if(dupes[i-1][0].sn == dupes[i][0].sn ) {
    if(dupes[i-1][0].partNum == dupes[i][0].partNum ) {
      result.push(dupes[i-1]);
      result.push(dupes[i]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

**Without mutation** :  You can declare the result array inside of the function, and since you are not changing dupes, the function will be pure.

```js
var dupes = [
[{ sn: 001, partNum: 2505}],
[{ sn: 001, partNum: 9999}],
[{ sn: 001, partNum: 9999}],
[{ sn: 002, partNum: 1234}],
[{ sn: 002, partNum: 1234}],
[{ sn: 003, partNum: 555}],
[{ sn: 003, partNum: 8675}]]


function onlyDuplicates(dupes) {
  var result = [];
  for(i =1; i<dupes.length; i++) {
    if(dupes[i-1][0].sn == dupes[i][0].sn ) {
      if(dupes[i-1][0].partNum == dupes[i][0].partNum ) {
        result.push(dupes[i-1]);
        result.push(dupes[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(onlyDuplicates(dupes));
```

Comment: I had thought about doing something similar to this but isn't "push" a mutation of the array? I know that the array `result` is an empty array and will be scoped within the function but does that make the function itself "impure" due to the mutation? Or is the function still pure as long as no mutations reach outside of the scope of the function?

Comment: @JustinGagnon i have added a solution with no mutations also

Comment: @JohnEllmore is this what you want?

Comment: Your solution is wrong. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52018049/783743) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

McRist's solution has a lot of problems. For example, it doesn't find duplicates if they aren't next to each other:

```js
var dupes = [ [ { sn: 001, partNum: 2505 } ]
            , [ { sn: 001, partNum: 9999 } ] // element 1
            , [ { sn: 002, partNum: 1234 } ] // element 2
            , [ { sn: 001, partNum: 9999 } ] // duplicate of element 1
            , [ { sn: 002, partNum: 1234 } ] // duplicate of element 2
            , [ { sn: 003, partNum: 555  } ]
            , [ { sn: 003, partNum: 8675 } ]
            ];

var result = [];

for (var i = 0, j = 1; j < dupes.length; i++, j++) {
    if (dupes[i][0].sn      === dupes[j][0].sn &&
        dupes[i][0].partNum === dupes[j][0].partNum) {
        result.push(dupes[i]);
        result.push(dupes[j]);
    }
}

// empty array, even though there are duplicates
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Even worse, if there are more than two contiguous duplicates then it returns extra elements:

```js
var dupes = [ [ { sn: 001, partNum: 2505 } ]
            , [ { sn: 001, partNum: 9999 } ] // element 1
            , [ { sn: 001, partNum: 9999 } ] // duplicate of element 1
            , [ { sn: 001, partNum: 9999 } ] // duplicate of element 1
            , [ { sn: 003, partNum: 555  } ]
            , [ { sn: 003, partNum: 8675 } ]
            ];

var result = [];

for (var i = 0, j = 1; j < dupes.length; i++, j++) {
    if (dupes[i][0].sn      === dupes[j][0].sn &&
        dupes[i][0].partNum === dupes[j][0].partNum) {
        result.push(dupes[i]);
        result.push(dupes[j]);
    }
}

// four elements, even though there are only three duplicates
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Here's a solution that correctly returns only those elements which are duplicates. In addition, it doesn't use mutation of any sort:

```js
var dupes = [ [ { sn: 001, partNum: 2505 } ]
            , [ { sn: 001, partNum: 9999 } ] // element 1
            , [ { sn: 002, partNum: 1234 } ] // element 2
            , [ { sn: 002, partNum: 1234 } ] // duplicate of element 2
            , [ { sn: 002, partNum: 1234 } ] // duplicate of element 2
            , [ { sn: 001, partNum: 9999 } ] // duplicate of element 1
            , [ { sn: 003, partNum: 555  } ]
            , [ { sn: 003, partNum: 8675 } ]
            ];

const duplicates = (xs, eq) =>
    xs.filter((x, i) =>      // filter those elements
        xs.some((y, j) =>    // for which there's another element
            i !== j &&       // which is not the same and
            eq(x, y)));      // is a duplicate

const eq = ([x], [y]) =>     // two elements are the same if
    x.sn      === y.sn &&    // they have the same serial number and
    x.partNum === y.partNum; // the same part number

// correctly returns all five duplicates
console.log(JSON.stringify(duplicates(dupes, eq)));
```

Hope that helps.